# Finding if a group of possible times falls within another range.

Tags: time, range

So I have a task which requires me to find when a certain order runs through a set period of time.

E.g. Task runs 10:30 - 13:30 and the range of times I am interested in is 11:00 to 12:30 - how do I highlight when said task runs through this time?

I can do the obvious whereby if the task finishes between 11:00 and 12:30, the cell is highlighted. But I am struggling with how to select this when the start is before the time range and the finish is after.

Any suggestions on how to get started are greatly appreciated?

Thank You

Comment: Did you have any particular programming language in mind ? Please tag responsibly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql you could use these queries:

http://salman-w.blogspot.nl/2012/06/sql-query-overlapping-date-ranges.html